# Mutation response coming in array I want to show mutation array response in Subscription in AppSync Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, amazon-aurora

I have mutation as

```
type Mutation {
    createMessage(input: MessageInput): [Message]
}

type Subscription {
    messageCreated(room: String): [Message]
       @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createMessage"])
}
```

I tested subscription and mutation by firing mutation in one tab and in other tab I have fired subscription, got data in mutation as array of objects but not getting any response from subscription (I want response as array of object same as mutation).

```
mutation createMessageWithMedia {
  createMessage(input: { metaType: Image, receiver: "16140a37-fa4e-4d04-aeda-bbc41a0726b1", room: "45a87f5b-ef9e-41cd-9cd7-f3e2f4946d31_16140a37-fa4e-4d04-aeda-bbc41a0726b1", type: Media, 
  media: [{
    bucket: "bucketname",
    path: "file/file1"
    url: "urlOfS3"
  },{
    bucket: "bucketname",
    path: "file/file1"
    url: "urlOfS3"
  }] }) {
    room
    bucket
    path
    url
    receiver 
    sender 
    metaType
    type
    id
  }
}
```

As above is my request for mutation. Then I'm firing join query which gives array of objects with media details. (I'm using Aurora Serverless with MySql). Pardon for delay

Comment: The data send to subscribers is the data requested by the client sending the mutation request.  Can you add to your question the exact mutation and subscription requests you used ?  You just posted the type and we can not answer your question just with this info.

Comment: Can you please share the schema you used in schema.graphql? It would be usefull to me.

Comment: @Blq56 can't share the schema for some reason but I can share ideas if you want!